# Check volume serial number within a bat file

Tags: batch-file, serial-number

Im writing a batch script to run on a flash drive. I need to validate the volume serial number of flash drive inside the code, therefore nobody should be able to run it from a different location.

Does anyone know how to validate serial number inside a batch file?

Example:

```
IF %VOL%==ABCD GOTO A ELSE EXIT
```

Comment: Given batch files are plaintext, what use would validating it there be? The user could simply alter the volume information.

Comment: Im planing to convert bat file into a exe

Comment: I'm just wondering how could _anyone_ penetrate this fortress of defense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are several different ways to achieve the same thing, the original DOS/Windows command *intended* to manage volumes and serial numbers is `VOL`:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 tokens=5" %%a in ('vol %~D0') do set Serial=%%a
if %Serial% equ ABCD-EF01 do (
    echo Valid serial number!
)
```

Comment: currently i am using MS dos 6.22 , unfortunately these all solution couldn't help me to reach my requirement. please advice me to find out another way with correct syntax for proper execution on MS Dos 6.22

Comment: @Aacini, +1: nice. Forgot about `vol`.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) and do something like:

```
wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get volumeserialnumber
```

See parameter types in the link mentioned.

Edit:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ("wmic logicaldisk where deviceid = 'C:' get volumeserialnumber") do (
  set SERIAL=%%j
  goto :DONE
)
:DONE
echo  SERIAL=%SERIAL%

if "%SERIAL%"=="BLAH" (
   echo "Bluh"
)
```

Comment: @yrk - Change the where clause to look at the drive letter where the  batch is executing from: `where deviceid = '%~d0'`. Also make sure to remove the hyphen from the right side of the IF comparison. DIR hyphenates the serial number, WMIC does not.